# Changing the font style for chapters, sections and subsections

Tags: miktex, titlesec

Can anyone please help me change the font style (say the LaTeX font: accanthis) only for the chapter name while the text in the article still has a palatino font (I am using `\usepackage{palantino}`).

I went through the `titlesec` package info but couldn't figure out how this could be done.

Answer (score 2):

Use `\titleformat` from package `titlesec` to change the chapter font. For the lower levels you can use the stared version of this command.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{accanthis}
\usepackage{palatino}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}
  [display]
  {\Huge\bfseries\accanthis}
  {\huge\chaptertitlename\space\thechapter}
  {20pt}
  {}

\titleformat*{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\accanthis}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalfont\large\bfseries\accanthis}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Note that you have to load `accanthis` before `palatino`.

[image]

---

If you only want to change the font settings for the section headings you could also use package `sectsty` instead `titlesec`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{accanthis}
\usepackage{palatino}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\chaptertitlefont{\Huge\bfseries\accanthis}
\chapternumberfont{\huge\bfseries\accanthis}
\sectionfont{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\accanthis}
\subsectionfont{\normalfont\large\bfseries\accanthis}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

---

But if you can use a KOMA-Script class it would be really easy:

```
\documentclass[emulatestandardclasses]{scrbook}
\usepackage{accanthis}
\usepackage{palatino}

\addtokomafont{chapter}{\accanthis}
\addtokomafont{section}{\accanthis}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\accanthis}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: How is that doable with Helvetica instead of Accanthis? Loading `\usepackage[scaled=.90]{helvet}` and changing `\accanthis` to `\helvet` gives me an undefined control sequence error.

Comment: Package `helvet` does not provide `\helvet`, it changes the default sans serif font to `helvet`. So you can use `\sffamily`.

Comment: That did not work for me, but I figured out another way. Thank you though!